# How to 'define' a datatype in C++?

Tags: c++

I was solving a CodeChef problem which asked to calculate the factorial of input. The range of input is **100**. Here's the problem's link.

https://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL2

So, there is one method to solve the factorial of 100 by using arrays because I used the 'Insertion sort' method but there's a *time limit exceeded* error. So
I came up with another method by using **unsigned long long int** datatype. I defined *int* *unsigned long long int* but it's not working. I'll be if you help fix it.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

#define int unsigned long long;
int main() {
    int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    if(1<=t<=100){
    while (t--) {
        cin>>n;
        if(1<=n<=100){
            int fact=1;
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
                fact*=i;
            }
            cout<<fact<<endl;
        }
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just find replace `int` with `unsigned long long`? Don't `#define` any c++ keywords.

Comment: The factorial of 100 is much larger than 64 bits.

Comment: If you want a smaller name, use a typedef, eg: `typedef unsigned long long ull;`

Comment: Please elaborate on *"not working"*.

Comment: See this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/ - a nice explanation of using arrays to hold the digits of enormous numbers which don't fit into 64-bit integer

Comment: As @RetiredNinja commented, the idea you came up with (using `unsigned long long`) is wrong. 100! is about [9.3e157](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%21) while the largest `unsigned long long` is about [1.8e19](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E64).

Comment: Do note that you recieved a "Time limit Exceeded" error, not "Wrong answer" error.
So the problem is not with the type of your integer, but the complexity of your code

Comment: Thanks, for your contribution and for helping. I mistook 158 decimal places with 15 when I have viewed the limit of datatype ` unsigned long long` and almost forgot its limit is 15 digits and I need 158. Since I was in hurry and taught it would work. Anyway, a thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`100!` is way too big for a `64` bit integer. It has `158` digits. You have to implement the BigInteger library. Hopefully, @[LightOj](https://lightoj.com/) Judge creator @Jane Alom Jan has a nice implementation that you can check. I am sharing his implementation, you can modify and test this for this problem.

```
#include <cstdio>
 
#include <string>
 
#include <algorithm>
 
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
 
 
struct Bigint {
 
    // representations and structures
 
    string a; // to store the digits
 
    int sign; // sign = -1 for negative numbers, sign = 1 otherwise
 
 
 
    // constructors
 
    Bigint() {} // default constructor
 
    Bigint( string b ) { (*this) = b; } // constructor for string
 
 
 
    // some helpful methods
 
    int size() { // returns number of digits
 
        return a.size();
 
    }
 
    Bigint inverseSign() { // changes the sign
 
        sign *= -1;
 
        return (*this);
 
    }
 
    Bigint normalize( int newSign ) { // removes leading 0, fixes sign
 
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i > 0 && a[i] == '0'; i-- )
 
            a.erase(a.begin() + i);
 
        sign = ( a.size() == 1 && a[0] == '0' ) ? 1 : newSign;
 
        return (*this);
 
    }
 
 
 
    // assignment operator
 
    void operator = ( string b ) { // assigns a string to Bigint
 
        a = b[0] == '-' ? b.substr(1) : b;
 
        reverse( a.begin(), a.end() );
 
        this->normalize( b[0] == '-' ? -1 : 1 );
 
    }
 
 
 
    // conditional operators
 
    bool operator < ( const Bigint &b ) const { // less than operator
 
        if( sign != b.sign ) return sign < b.sign;
 
        if( a.size() != b.a.size() )
 
            return sign == 1 ? a.size() < b.a.size() : a.size() > b.a.size();
 
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) if( a[i] != b.a[i] )
 
            return sign == 1 ? a[i] < b.a[i] : a[i] > b.a[i];
 
        return false;
 
    }
 
    bool operator == ( const Bigint &b ) const { // operator for equality
 
        return a == b.a && sign == b.sign;
 
    }
 
 
 
 
    // mathematical operators
 
    Bigint operator + ( Bigint b ) { // addition operator overloading
 
        if( sign != b.sign ) return (*this) - b.inverseSign();
 
        Bigint c;
 
        for(int i = 0, carry = 0; i<a.size() || i<b.size() || carry; i++ ) {
 
            carry+=(i<a.size() ? a[i]-48 : 0)+(i<b.a.size() ? b.a[i]-48 : 0);
 
            c.a += (carry % 10 + 48);
 
            carry /= 10;
 
        }
 
        return c.normalize(sign);
 
    }
 
    Bigint operator - ( Bigint b ) { // subtraction operator overloading
 
        if( sign != b.sign ) return (*this) + b.inverseSign();
 
        int s = sign; sign = b.sign = 1;
 
        if( (*this) < b ) return ((b - (*this)).inverseSign()).normalize(-s);
 
        Bigint c;
 
        for( int i = 0, borrow = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
 
            borrow = a[i] - borrow - (i < b.size() ? b.a[i] : 48);
 
            c.a += borrow >= 0 ? borrow + 48 : borrow + 58;
 
            borrow = borrow >= 0 ? 0 : 1;
 
        }
 
        return c.normalize(s);
 
    }
 
    Bigint operator * ( Bigint b ) { // multiplication operator overloading
 
        Bigint c("0");
 
        for( int i = 0, k = a[i] - 48; i < a.size(); i++, k = a[i] - 48 ) {
 
            while(k--) c = c + b; // ith digit is k, so, we add k times
 
            b.a.insert(b.a.begin(), '0'); // multiplied by 10
 
        }
 
        return c.normalize(sign * b.sign);
 
    }
 
    Bigint operator / ( Bigint b ) { // division operator overloading
 
        if( b.size() == 1 && b.a[0] == '0' ) b.a[0] /= ( b.a[0] - 48 );
 
        Bigint c("0"), d;
 
        for( int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++ ) d.a += "0";
 
        int dSign = sign * b.sign; b.sign = 1;
 
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
 
            c.a.insert( c.a.begin(), '0');
 
            c = c + a.substr( i, 1 );
 
            while( !( c < b ) ) c = c - b, d.a[i]++;
 
        }
 
        return d.normalize(dSign);
 
    }
 
    Bigint operator % ( Bigint b ) { // modulo operator overloading
 
        if( b.size() == 1 && b.a[0] == '0' ) b.a[0] /= ( b.a[0] - 48 );
 
        Bigint c("0");
 
        b.sign = 1;
 
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
 
            c.a.insert( c.a.begin(), '0');
 
            c = c + a.substr( i, 1 );
 
            while( !( c < b ) ) c = c - b;
 
        }
 
        return c.normalize(sign);
 
    }
 
 
 
 
    // output method
 
    void print() {
 
        if( sign == -1 ) putchar('-');
 
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) putchar(a[i]);
 
    }
 
};
 
 
 
int main() {
 
    Bigint a, b, c; // declared some Bigint variables
 
 
 
    /////////////////////////
 
    // taking Bigint input //
 
    /////////////////////////
 
    string input; // string to take input
 
 
 
    cin >> input; // take the Big integer as string
 
    a = input; // assign the string to Bigint a
 
 
 
    cin >> input; // take the Big integer as string
 
    b = input; // assign the string to Bigint b
 
 
 
    //////////////////////////////////
 
    // Using mathematical operators //
 
    //////////////////////////////////
 
 
 
    c = a + b; // adding a and b
 
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
 
    puts(""); // newline
 
 
 
    c = a - b; // subtracting b from a
 
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
 
    puts(""); // newline
 
 
 
    c = a * b; // multiplying a and b
 
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
 
    puts(""); // newline
 
 
 
    c = a / b; // dividing a by b
 
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
 
    puts(""); // newline
 
 
 
    c = a % b; // a modulo b
 
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
 
    puts(""); // newline
 
 
 
    /////////////////////////////////
 
    // Using conditional operators //
 
    /////////////////////////////////
 
 
 
    if( a == b ) puts("equal"); // checking equality
 
    else puts("not equal");
 
 
 
    if( a < b ) puts("a is smaller than b"); // checking less than operator
 
 
 
    return 0;
 
}
```

**As the problem has a source limit of 2000 bytes so adding the hole BigInteger library will cross the source limit.**

So only string multiplication can be done here.

A clean approach of multiplication is given below using `C++`

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        vector<int> arr;
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        arr.push_back(1);
        int carry = 0;

        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
            vector<int> t;
            for(int j = arr.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                int r = arr[j] * i + carry;
                carry = r / 10;
                t.push_back(r % 10);
            }
            while(carry){
                t.push_back(carry % 10);
                carry /= 10;
            }
            reverse(t.begin(), t.end());
            arr = t;
        }
        for(auto el : arr){
            cout << el;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
2
10
100
```

**Output**

```
3628800
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

Also adding an easy `python` implementation

```
test = int(input())

for i in range(0, test):
    n = int(input())
    res = 1
    for j in range(2, n + 1):
        res = res * j
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 4):

Factorial of 100 is way too large for 64 bits, it will overflow regardless. The point is that you should implement your own big-number class, or use an existing implementation like the one in Boost.

Factorial of 100 has 158 digits!

Answer (score 1):

Already 3 days old question, but anyway.

The solution is a rather simple task. We can do it like we would do it on a piece of paper. We use a `std::vector` of digits to hold the number. Because the result will be already too big for an `unsigned long long` for 22!.

The answer will be exact. Also the code is short and compact.

With such an approach the calculation is simple. I do not even know what to explain further.

Please be careful with the runtime. It will be extremely long for big numbers. If speed is an issue, then use the original BigInt header only lib.

Please see the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Calculate n!   Enter n (max 10000): ";
    if (unsigned int input{}; (std::cin >> input) && (input <= 10000)) {

        // Here we store the resulting number as single digits
        std::vector<unsigned int> result(3000, 0);  // Magic number. Is big enough for 100000!
        result.back() = 1;                          // Start calculation with 1 (from right to left)

        // Multiply up to the given input value
        for (unsigned int count = 2; count <= input; count++)
        {
            unsigned int sum{}, remainder{};
            unsigned int i = result.size() - 1;     // Calculate from right to left
            while (i > 0)
            {
                // Simple multiplication like on a piece of paper
                sum = result[i] * count + remainder;
                result[i--] = sum % 10;
                remainder = sum / 10;
            }
        }
        // Show output. Supporess leading zeroes
        bool showZeros{ false };
        for (const unsigned int i : result) {
            if ((i != 0) || showZeros) {
                std::cout << i;
                showZeros = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Wrong input.";
}
```

---

Developed and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2.

Additionally compiled and tested with clang11.0 and gcc10.2

Language: C++17